# Gradle bootRun not working with SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE but works with spring.profiles.active

Tags: java, spring, gradle

MacOS Monterey.
Spring Boot 2.4.5.
Gradle 7.4.2

The question is pretty simple.

This one doesn't work:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local ./gradlew bootRun
```

This one works:

```
./gradlew bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=local'
```

Under "works", I understand that the profile is being successfully passed to Gradle task.

What I have read is that **SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE** - is OS environment variable, while **spring.profiles.active** is System property.

Still not clear why the option `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local ./gradlew bootRun` doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using windows os?

Comment: @Nemanja updated: macOS Monterey

Comment: Did you set enviroment variable SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE?

Comment: Could you please share gradle and spring boot versions? Just tried on the following configuration: https://pastebin.com/k3XUd7bx with spring boot 2.7.0 and `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local ./gradlew bootRun` works just fine

Comment: @geobreze Spring Boot 2.4.5, Gradle 7.4.2

Comment: don't you need to use the `export` keyword in bash when setting the OS variable? (or `set` when you use fish) What does `printenv` give you after running the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local` command

Comment: @LeshaPipiev just tried using the versions you've provided and everything still works fine both in iTerm and Terminal (both bash and zsh with Oh My Zsh). Maybe there is a misconfiguration in your project? Does this issue reproducible on the clean project created using https://start.spring.io/?

Comment: Guys, appreciate your help. Now, I can't reproduce the issue and can't explain what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Break this into multiple lines

```
$ export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local 
$ ./gradlew bootRun
```